# Whats the story with a guy discovering an old tv program and getting trapped inside

Tags: story-identification

I remember a guy finding an old black and white TV program but no one believes him when he tries to tell him and as he watches it the same episode repeats but the background characters change he becomes obsessed with it and eventually gets trapped in the program as one of the background characters I don't remember what's it's called or what it's from

Comment: This wouldn't by any chance be the movie *Pleasantville*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleasantville_(film)

Comment: This "story" you ask about is a book or a short story?  (The proposed answers seem to be movies or TV series episodes not "stories".)

Answer (score 2):

That's an American Dad episode. The episode title is 'Rabbit Ears'. The fictional show with in a show is 'Nighthawks Hideaway'.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).